# Send message and files to whatsapp using laravel

Tags: laravel, whatsapp

How can I send WhatsApp message using laravel? 
Please help me to find out with the environment setup.

```
wp::send('work.data', ['user' => $seleteced_pic], function ($m)
```

Should it be this way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Laravel there are no build in ability to send messages via WhatsApp.

You will need to integrate with WhatsApp API or use third party serves.

The first google search give me this result. https://www.twilio.com/blog/create-laravel-php-notification-channel-whatsapp-twilio 
One of the third party serves that simplify iteration with messaging serves.

But you could integrate with WhatsApp directly. 
https://www.whatsapp.com/business/api

Comment: when integrating with WhatsApp directly , does it require a business account and client should give a permission to send them messages ? or you can just send it directly

Comment: @MoradAl-Rowaihi  probably you should contact WhatsApp support for this particular question.
And maybe create a separate question on stake overflow. To replay it when you figure things out.